# CSS write element tag near to text

Tags: html, css

I want to have the texts which follow the choices ("A", "B" etc.) in the same line as those choices.

```css
.answer {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0 #b7b7b7;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div  class="choices">
  <div class="answer">A) <p style="">casa</p></div>
  <div class="answer">B) <p>kasa</p></div>
  <div class="answer">C) <p>fsdfsdf</p></div>
  <div class="answer">D) <p>sefsfesf</p></div>
  <div class="answer">E) <p>sfesfesfs</p></div>
</div>
```

[image]

How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your problem/wish is to have the `p` tag text in the same line as "A)", "B)" etc.?

If yes, add this CSS rule:

```
.answer p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```css
.answer {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0 #b7b7b7;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.answer p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">
  <div class="answer">A)
    <p style="">casa</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">B)
    <p>kasa</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">C)
    <p>fsdfsdf</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">D)
    <p>sefsfesf</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">E)
    <p>sfesfesfs</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RayeesAC Not in all cases: `inline-block` has the disadvantage that if the text is longer than one line, it will completely go under the "A)" etc. again...